# bootstrap media not showing image src but grid thumbnail is

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, media

Is there something special about bootstrap media that I am missing? 
The below media code is not giving me an image:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="media">
      <a class="media-left media-bottom" href="#">
        <img class="pull-left" src="air.jpeg">
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">Bottom aligned media</h4>
        <p>Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.</p>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the grid code for the same image is working:

```
div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="air.jpeg" alt="air feed">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Classify millions of tweets on important legislation </h3>
        <p>Input the legislation name or bill number and measure how the internet views it.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">More</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Data</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please show demo code at https://jsfiddle.net/
There might some issue in css, You wrapped image in anchor. But not in grid code.

Comment: Hi Prasad, I targeted the problem. Images are only loading on my home.html. My about page and contact page are not loading images. Is there reason why the home page is loading but others are not?

Comment: Can you please place demo code at https://jsfiddle.net/ . It helps to debug your issue. There might very small html tag issue. If image is loading in one page. If you given appropriate path. It should load in all other.